# Pagination in React with REST API

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React recently, and I want to know how to paginate in React.
I have implemented a simple REST API that can fetch data from the database and return JSON file like this:

```
count: total number of data
start: starting index of data
limit: how many data per page
next: api to fetch next page of data
previous: api to fetch previous page of data

{
    "count": 17,
    "start": 1
    "limit": 5,
    "next": "/User/page?start=6&limit=5",
    "previous": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "id": ,
            "last_name": "",
            "password": "",
        },
        ...
    ], 
}
```

I want so I want to add two links at the bottom of each page, so that i can go forward and backwards.

My current React code looks like this, I can fetch the data from first page, but I'm not sure how to get to the next page

```
class Users extends Component{
    state={
        count:undefined,
        limit:undefined,
        next:'',
        previous:'',
        start:undefined,
        results:[]
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/User/page').then(response=>{
            this.setState({
                results:response.data.results,
                count:response.data.count,
                limit:response.data.limit,
                next:response.data.next,
                previous:response.data.previous,
                start:response.data.start
            })

        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.previous)
        console.log(this.state.next)
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.results.map((user)=>{return <User key={user.id} user={user}/>})}

                //I know this wont work
                //<a href={this.state.previous} style={{color:'#4c4c4c'}}>prev</a>
                //<br/>
                //<a href={this.state.next} style={{color:'#4c4c4c'}}>next</a>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution, which is to add two button and two onClick event which will run setState to refresh content in state.

Comment: even though the content is changed, the link in the browser didn't change, the link will always be the same, so how to solve this?

Comment: That depends on what you are using to control your routing.

Comment: If you are using `react-router` you would replace your `<a href=` with a `Link` component.  Your `Users` component would need to set the `start` parameter on the API calls in order to fetch the right data when someone goes to some URL like `/users/page/3`.

Comment: i use react-route-dom and it looks like <Route path='/User/page' component={Users}></Route>, how can I add parameters after this route path? like page num, is it possible to user 'User/path/<int:page>'?

Comment: I would make your URLs lowercase, but that's just a preference.  You would write your route like `<Route path="/users/page/:pageNumber" component={Users}>`.  When the route loads the component, it provides a prop `match` so you can look at `props.match.params.pageNumber` to get the value.  There's a lot of info in [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route).  FYI, I think the params are always `string` so you would need to call `parseInt`.

Comment: thank you, i'll take a look the docs

Comment: I checked the docs and now I use <Route path="/users/page/:pageNumber" component={Users}>, I am able to manually change :pageNumber in the browser, like user/page/1, user/page/2, and it will display the correct answer.

Comment: but i got two problems here. The first is that there's no default value so when I click the link to see users, I'll reach user/page which is empty, i need to manually add 1 to make everything work fine. is it possible to set the default value of :pageNumber to be 1?

Comment: And the second problem is that I have two buttons "prev" and "next" in Users component, I want to be able to change :pageNumber when I click buttons. For example, if current page is users/page/2, when I click "prev", I want to go to user/page/1 and if I click "next", I want to go to user/page/3. I can handle onClick event of buttons and get new data, but it would only change the content of the current page, user/page/2 will be updated to new data, but it won't take me to page/3 or page/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want what's shown on the page to reflect the URL in the address bar and vice-versa.  So rather than using local component state to control the page number, we will use a page number in the URL as the "single source of truth."

#### The Router

When declaring routes in `react-router-dom` you can use a colon `:` followed by a variable name to match a dynamic variable.  This variable will be available to the component through either `props.match.params` or the `useParams` hook.

In our case, we want a variable for `pageNumber`. The primary route looks like this:

```
<Route path="/users/page/:pageNumber" component={Users} />
```

You asked if you should redirect traffic from `/users` to `/users/page/1`, and in my opinion we should do the opposite.  We can use the `Redirect` component inside our `Switch` to handle the redirection.

When routing traffic to the `/users` page, it is important that this page goes **after** the one with the page number, because otherwise it will match all of the pages.  You could also use the param `exact`, but you don't need to as long as the order is right.  It's a general principle of react-router that more specific paths always come first.

Likewise, we want to put our `Redirect` **before** the `Route` which would send those users to the `Users` page.  We will still send them there, but we want to redirect first.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect from="/users/page/1" to="/users" />
    <Route path="/users/page/:pageNumber" component={Users} />
    <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

#### The Component

Our `Users` component can figure out which page to render by looking at the `pageNumber` from `props.match.params.pageNumber` or the `useParams` hook.  URL params are always a `string`, so we need to use `parseInt` before using it in any mathematical operations.

When we are on the first page, there is no `pageNumber` param, so we need to default to `1` whenever the page number is empty.

```
const params = useParams();
const pageNumber = params.pageNumber ? parseInt(params.pageNumber, 10) : 1;
```

You would base your API call on the `pageNumber`.  You can use string literal syntax to compose the right URL string.

```
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/User/page?start=${1 + limit * (pageNumber - 1)}&limit=${limit}`);
```

The `Previous` and `Next` links should be shown conditionally, since there is no previous page from page 1.  You can use the results of your API call to see if there is a next page.

```
const hasPrevious = pageNumber > 1;
const hasNext = !!state.next;
```

We implement those links using the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.  The `to` param takes the path that we want to link to.  We will add and subtract from our current `pageNumber`.

```
<div>
   {hasPrevious && (
        <Link to={`/users/page/${pageNumber - 1}`}>Previous</Link>
    )}
    {hasNext && (
       <Link to={`/users/page/${pageNumber + 1}`}>Next</Link>
    )}
</div>
```

Obviously I don't have access to your API, but I [created a little demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64636871-lp4ug?file=/src/Users.jsx) to make sure that I got the pagination right.

For more information on the specific components used, make sure to check out the [React Router Docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components).